# minimal iptables firewall

Tags: ubuntu

I am intent on building a minimal iptables firewall within ubuntu server 14.04. Just to make sure that I am building my firewall correctly and executing it correctly I am running it through the community for verification. I do not quite understand the way `-o interface` and `-i interface` operate. Each time I look at different firewall rules they are configured differently so that complicates the way my rules are set up regarding `wan` and `lan` rules. The way I understand it is this way: **PC** > `-i interface` **LAN** `-o interface` > `-i interface` **WAN** `-o interface` > **INTERNET**. This also is true for `NAT` tables. `prerouting` > **NETWORK** `postrouting` and `forward` bypasses **NETWORK**.

This is a general ruleset to get the firewall functional if I am correct where `wan` is `eth0` and `lan` is `eth1`:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

This is my ruleset where `wan` is `eth0` and `lan` is `eth1`:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD -j DROP

iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT -j DROP

iptables -P OUTPUT -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -P PREROUTING ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -P POSTROUTING ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth1 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Also regarding the permenant execution of the firewall. After I edit this ruleset with `sudo nano -w /etc/rc.local` then use `sudo chmod 755 /etc/rc.local` and `sudo reboot` this ruleset will be permanent each time the device is booted?

Answer (score 0):

Before going farther. Look at "net filter tables" (`nftables`). It replaces iptables, iptables6, arptables, ...

nftables is: easier to use, more powerful, and newer. On recent systems iptables is a (legacy) front-end for nftables.

An example of an nftables rule set: to block direct network access of user `other`, and forcing them to use a proxy. It still has two counter, that were used in testing (they could be removed). Also `accept`ing, skuid "proxy-server" un-necessary. As this is the current policy.

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

table ip my_table {}
flush table my_table

table ip my_table {
    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
        skuid "other" jump restrict_chain;
        skuid "proxy-server" accept;
    }

    chain restrict_chain {
        counter;
        oifname != "lo" reject;
        tcp dport != "1080" reject;
        counter;
        accept;
    }
}
```